# How to Enable "Show Develop menu" in Safari

Tags: macos, safari

How to Enable "Show Develop menu" in Safari when "Show Develop menu in menu bar" is disabled out[image: Refer the image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go to terminal and type this (Close Safari before doing this step)

% defaults write com.apple.Safari IncludeDebugMenu 1

Got the answer from below site

Reference website:
http://hints.macworld.com/article.php?story=20030110063041629

Answer (score 1):

You can try Safe Boot mode by holding down the Shift key at startup (it's quite slow). After that, log in and then restart normally.

If this doesn't work, try to take a look to this answer: https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/401179/safari-developer-menu-disabled

Answer (score 0):

Other option may be updating Safari